# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Joiners.txt (Access Denied)

Tags: java, filereader, access-denied

Here is my problem. The path is true and the error is access denied.
 I tried other solution but none of them work for me.

```
//this is my arraylist which i give value from the txt
       ArrayList<Person> PersonArrayList = new ArrayList<Person>();     
        FileReader inFile = new 
        FileReader("C:\\Users\\canertasan\\Desktop");
        //this is my path but access denied is problem?
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(inFile);
        String InstaNameText;
        while ((InstaNameText = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
             PersonData.add(new Person(InstaNameText));
        inStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: is the `inStream.close();` on purpose inside your `while`?

Comment: Where is your filename in the file path?

Comment: Is `Desktop` a folder?

Comment: yes Stephen it is @StephenC

Comment: I dont know where should i give the filename @SandeepRandhawa

Comment: I try to do after while close the inStream file. @EmersonCod

Comment: @CanerTaşan `C:\\Users\\canertasan\\Desktop\\yourfilename` like this.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop isn't a file, it's a folder
FileReader should be given a file name as parameter

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Joiners.txt"; //Fullpath txt file
String currentLine; //Current line
FileReader fr = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    fr = new FileReader(filename);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);


    while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(currentLine);
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    if (br != null)
        br.close();
    if (fr != null)
        fr.close();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Update answer. I helped?

Answer (score 1):

The pathname refers to a folder not a file, and you cannot open a folder as a `Reader`.

The solution depends on what you are trying to do.

- If you are trying to read the names of the files in the folder, then use `File.list() -> String[]` and iterate the array.
- If you are trying to read the content of all of the files in the folder, then use `File.listFiles() -> File[]` and iterate the array.  For each file, open, read lines and then close the file.
- If you are trying to read the content of a specific file in the `Desktop` folder, then use the pathname for the file, not the folder.